# Raspberry pi 4 not booting when rotating the display

Tags: boot-issues, screen, pi-4, raspbian-buster

When booting Gentoo with the UI interface and Raspian Buster Lite (July 2019 version) on the Raspberry Pi 4 (2 Gigas of RAM) the boot is done perfectly and it is possible to work with the PI.
However when setting `display_rotate=3` on config.txt the screen is very shifted to the right and the boot process hangs.
[image]
I've also tried to use `hdmi_safe=1` but it did not work.

P.S. The same screen I use with Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspberry Zero W and I have no issues when rotating.

Comment: Is your Raspbian version up to date? `sudo apt update;sudo apt dist-upgrade-y;sudo reboot` will get the latest with lots of RPi4 fixes in it.

Comment: Display rotate doesn’t work on the Pi4. There is an alternative, but I haven’t tried it

Comment: @Milliways What's the alternative?

Comment: I don't know (or I would have posted it) but it was reported on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ The Pi4 has a new Video Core.

Comment: @Dougie Did not work.  ☹️